# android syntax problem with onActivtyresult

Tags: android, syntax, android-activity, android-intent

I am a beginner to android. 
I am trying to figure out the errors I am getting when using the following syntax:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

The following are the errors: 1.void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult.  2.Syntax error on token "," ";" expected.  3. same as 2.  4.Syntax error on token "(" ";" expected.  5.Syntax error on token ")" ";" expected.
Sorry if you find this question trivial.

Comment: I really cannot understand why void is an invalid type. I have used onActivityresult earlier with the same specs.

Comment: I believe if you check your code and put the `;` in a proper place, then the error will disappear.

Comment: I have tried it. But the errors continue to occur.

Comment: I cant imagine, that you post the proper code, where the errors occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your class extends `Activity`.  I'm also assuming that you are closing the method properly:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Log.d("TAG","requestCode = "+requestCode+" / resultCode = " +resultCode );
    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: I had closed the method. But I had not included super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
I included it now and still the problem persists.

Comment: So you are definitely trying to do this within an `Activity`?  This isn't within a private local class or within some other method?  Perhaps you have put this method definition within your `onCreate` method, or within one of the other overridden methods?  If so, move it outside the overridden method.

Comment: Thank you. I had made that mistake.

Comment: Doh, this was my exact mistake also, had it accidentally within the onCreate after a setOnListener...nub mistake! ty

Answer (score 0):

Write outside the `oncreate()`. This may solve your problem

```
public class User_info extends Activity {

Button b1;
EditText usernm , pwd ;
int request_code;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_info);
    request_code=1;
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    usernm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pwd);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent();
            startActivityForResult(i, request_code);

        }


    });


}

public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent i )
{

}

}
```

Comment: This question got an accepted answer over three and a half years ago. If you want to add something to the conversation, you need to at least give an understandable explanation, not just dump a bunch of code.